# Can humans pollinate Catharanthus by hand?

Tags: seeds, pollination

Can we pollinate [Catharanthus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catharanthus) without bees or insects? If yes, then how to do it?

Due to the floral structure of the Rosy Periwinkle, they require insects such as butterflies and moths that have long tongues, and serve as better pollinators for this plant. The flowers of the Madagascar Periwinkle are often visited by a wide variety of insects including butterflies, moths, bees and even beetles. Furthermore, other studies have shown that the Madagascar Periwinkle is a very unique species within its family because of its self-compatibility meaning that they are able to pollinate themselves.

But how we can do it if we want to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is using a painting brush to move the pollen from the stamens onto the stigma.

Just make sure the hairs of the brush get inside the flower and twist it around a bit, so you can be sure that they touch the pistil in the center.

Read the [short description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hand-pollination) on Wikipedia or search "brush pollination" on Youtube.

This is an example:
[image]

Comment: stemen or stigma is not visible , it is inside the flower

Comment: @user3110224 That's why you need the paintbrush, otherwise you could have used a fingertip. The fine hairs of the brush gently reach the center of the flower without harming it. You don't need to see inside to do it.

Comment: Can you please provide steps how to do that

Comment: Please see my updated answer.